# $[4, 5) \bigcup (8,9]$ a subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology - finding open and closed subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = [4, 5) \bigcup (8,9]$ be a subspace topology, $\tau_X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology, $\tau_S$.

I am looking for subsets that are -

1. Open but not closed
2. Closed but not open
3. Open and closed
4. Neither open nor closed

**1.**

Let $A = (4, 5) \bigcup (8,9) \subset \tau_S$.

$A = \big(4, 5) \bigcup (8,9) \bigcap X$  so $A \in \tau_X$. So $A$ is open.

$A^c = \{4\} \bigcup \{9\}$. There is no $U \in \tau_S$ such that $A^c = U \bigcap X$. So $A^c$ is not open. Hence $A$ is not closed.

**2.**

Let $A = \{4\}$.

There is no $U \in \tau_S$ such that $A = U \bigcap X$. So $A$ is not open.

$A^c = (4, 5) \bigcup (8,9]$. This is open - $A^c = (4, 5) \bigcup (8, 10) \bigcap X$, and $(4, 5) \bigcup (8, 10) \in \tau_S$. So $A$ is closed.

**3.**

Let $A = [4, 5)$.

$A = (3, 5) \bigcap X$. So $A$ is open.

$A^c = (8, 9]$, which is open by the reason just stated, so $A$ is closed.

**4.**

I haven't been able to find a subset of $X$ that is neither open nor closed. Does one exist? Are 1-3 correct?

Comment: Why not $[4.5,4.6)$?  This is not closed because it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and similarly it isn't open because it isn't open in $\mathbb{R}$.